# In development with Nuxt3+Nuxt UI, tailwindcss may encounter errors

Tags: css, nuxt3

I'm developing with Nuxt3+Nuxt UI. When I save some Vue files and reload the page, I encounter the following error.

```
[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/_nuxt/node_modules/tailwindcss/tailwind.css"
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXOx8.png)

The behavior on the screen is that the layout briefly breaks, then the CSS is applied. Therefore, I suspect that the generation of tailwindcss and the timing of the page loading are not synchronized. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/ui": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/eslint": "^8",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.10.0",
    "ress": "^5.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.70.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.15",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.27"
  }
}
```

By setting ssr:false in nuxt.config.ts, the issue no longer occurs. However, this is not a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Don't have the link on me right now but this is a known Vue router issue. Check some Github issues/discussions.